# Simple vs bracketed usings C#

Tags: c#, coding-style

Visual Studio often recommends the 'simple using' statement rather than brackets. However, which is actually better?

I quite like the simple using statement, but I can see it potentially causing problems since you can't see the scope. The simple using seems a bit less clear that it's a using statement.

#### 1. Simple using

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[4096];
using FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(...);
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)) > 0)
{
    ... // Do something
}
```

#### 2. Bracketed using

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[4096];
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(...))
{
    while ((bytesRead = plaintext.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ... // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: In what situation can (1) become a problem?

Comment: This has always been a hack to Visual Studio's indentation rules to work around the fact that C# doesn't support multiple variables in one `using` statement; (2) becomes incredibly painful when you have multiple nested `using`s.

Comment: Close voters, this question is about a very specific topic (so voting with "needs more focus" is a sign of misunderstanding that close reason). And it is far from being opinionated (see my answer, there are pretty clear criteria when to use #1 or #2). Next time, try not to be so trigger-happy with the close-vote buttons, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The C# 8 using statement translates to try-finally blocks ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)).

Your example

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[4096];
using FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(...);
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)) > 0)
{
    ... // Do something
}
```

Will be translated to something like:

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[4096];
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(...);
try
{
   while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)) > 0)
   {
       ... // Do something
   }
}
finally()
{
   fileStream.Dispose();
}
```

Your concern that you can't see the scope is invalid. The object will always be disposed.

Coding style preferences are just that, preferences. Some people like option 1 and others like option 2. When nesting multiple usings, option 2 becomes a bit messy because of indentations. Doc Brown’s answer has some good objective criteria when to use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of #1:

- less indentation required (which affects readability specificially when more than one `using variable` is required)
- less "noise" in code, since less brackets are required

Disadvantages:

- only available in C# 8.0 (which works for .Net Core / .Net Standard, but is only experimentally supported for the classic .Net Framework)
- the call to `Dispose()` is tied to the outer scope of where the `using` statement is placed, whilst #2 introduces a new scope for each variable (so #1 provides less control about where the acquired resources are disposed).

So I would recommend to use #1 in case you don't need to stick to C# prior to version 8.0, and in case the enclosing function's scope is providing the required lifetime for the declared variables. If one of the two former conditions is not fulfilled, better use #2.

Comment: Most C# 8 features can be used with .NET Framework. See [this elaborate Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020770/10585586).

Comment: @RikD: ok, I missed that, but see the "Caveat" section at the end of that post.